# Run a background timer in native iOS Module with Objective C - React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, react-native, objective-c-2.0

My app requires to run a timer in the background continuously when an app is in the background and it should stop when app gets into the foreground.

The app is built with React Native and [it doesn't have any proper module](https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/background-timer-execution) to run in the background yet. So I created a [bridge](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios) between React Native Javascript and Native iOS.

I expose a ios native module can signal events to JavaScript without being invoked directly and passed an event to native code to invoke from javascript.

**TestManager.h**

```
//
//  TestManager.h
//
//  Created by Asbar Ali on 6/7/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Facebook. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface TestManager : RCTEventEmitter <RCTBridgeModule>

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

**TestManager.m**

```
//
//  TestManager.m
//  CrockfitMobile
//
//  Created by Asbar Ali on 6/7/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Facebook. All rights reserved.
//

#import "TestManager.h"

@implementation TestManager
{
  bool hasListeners;
}

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

- (NSArray<NSString *> *)supportedEvents
{
  return @[@"EventReminder"];
}

// Will be called when this module's first listener is added.
-(void)startObserving {
  hasListeners = YES;
  NSLog(@"Listener added");
}

// Will be called when this module's last listener is removed, or on dealloc.
-(void)stopObserving {
  hasListeners = NO;
    NSLog(@"Listner Removed");
}

- (void)TestEventReminderReceived:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  NSString *eventName = notification.userInfo[@"name"];
  if (hasListeners) { // Only send events if anyone is listening
    [self sendEventWithName:@"EventReminder" body:@{@"name": eventName}];
  }
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(timerStart:(NSString *)name location:(NSString *)location)
{
  NSLog(@"invoked by javaScript");
}

@end
```

following method in TestManager.m is called from a React Native(JavaScript)

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(timerStart:(NSString *)name location:(NSString *)location)
{
  NSLog(@"invoked by javaScript");
}
```

When I add the following code inside the above method, ***NSTimer is not firing.***

**NOTE:** This will work perfectly in ViewControllers

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self 
                                       selector:@selector(updateModel:) userInfo:str repeats:YES];
```

I found some answers for it. 
[Answ1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18098396/4322261)
[Answ2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23622475/4322261)

Then I realize that it could be a threading problem and need to call in the main thread.

> 1. How can I start a timer in subclass of RCTEventEmitter when app get into the background? (TestManager.m)
> 2. If we can't do it in this module, how can we do it?

Comment: You don't need to run in the background (not can you). Simply create a `Date` when your app moves to the background and determine the difference between then and "now" when it returns to the foreground

Comment: @ Paulw11 There are sets in the timer and I want to play beep sound after finish each set. So I can't do it when app is in the background (bcz timer doesn't run)

Comment: @ Paulw11 It works perfectly in android.

Comment: You can schedule a local notification